# urllib2 fails when URL has a port number appended

Tags: python, urllib2

The code below:

```
import urllib2
file = urllib2.urlopen("http://foo.bar.com:82")
```

works just fine on my mac (OS X 10.8.4 running Python 2.7.1.  It opens the URL and I can parse the file with no problems.

When I try the EXACT same code (these two lines) in GoDaddy Python 2.7.3 (or 2.4) I receive an error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error (111, 'Connection refused')
```

The problem has something to do with the port :82 that is an essential part of the address.  I have tried using a forwarding address with masking, etc., and nothing works.

Any idea why it would work in one environment and not in the other (ostensibly similar) environment?  Any ideas how to get around this?  I also tried Mechanize to no avail.   Previous posts have suggested focusing on urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler, but it works fine on my OS X environment without anything special.

Ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`Connection refused` means that your operating system tried to contact the remote host, but got a "closed port" message.

Most likely, this is because of a firewall between GoDaddy and `foo.bar.com`. Most likely, `foo.bar.com` is only reachable from your computer or your local network, but it also could be GoDaddy preventing access to strange ports.

Comment: I can run the same code on a different hosting service (that presumably does not have such a firewall).  I will poke around GoDaddy to see if there is a firewall setting or if I can get through for this specific port.  In the meantime, if anyone has had success with this (getting GoDaddy to open a port) I'd be thrilled to learn of it.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the GoDaddy support forums, it looks like they only support outgoing requests to ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) on their shared hosts.  See e.g.

http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/curl-to-ports-other-than-80/